# Permission denied when executing testng.xml via ssh

Tags: permissions

See attached screenshot. Please do let me know how to fix this issue ASAP.

[image]

Comment: can you please post a text-version, please?

Comment: Crystal ball says you don't have enough permissions on one of the intermediate directories. Try `ls /var/lib/jenkins/…/bsh*.jar` and move your way up until it stops failing.

Comment: I run this in openshift jenkins pod terminal "java -classpath /var/lib/jenkins/bin;/var/lib/jenkins/lib/* org.testng.TestNG testng.xml" but it shows me a permission denied to error saying "/var/lib/jenkins/CYOV3/lib/bsh-2.0b4.jar".

Answer (score 1):

You’re talking about

```
java -classpath /var/lib/jenkins/bin;/var/lib/Jenkins/CYOV3/lib/* org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

as if it were *a* command, but it’s not — it’s ***two*** commands
(separated by a `;`):

- `java -classpath /var/lib/jenkins/bin`, which causes the long usage/error message from `java`, because it’s an incomplete command,
  and
- `/var/lib/Jenkins/CYOV3/lib/* org.testng.TestNG testng.xml`, which globs (does pathname expansion on) the first word (because it contains `*`) and expands it to something like

  ```
  /var/lib/jenkins/CYOV3/lib/bsh-2.0b4.jar /var/lib/Jenkins/CYOV3/lib/foo /var/lib/Jenkins/CYOV3/lib/quux org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
  ```

  which fails because `/var/lib/jenkins/CYOV3/lib/bsh-2.0b4.jar`, being a JAR file (and not a script or a binary executable) doesn’t have execute permission.

You need to figure out what you are trying to do, and then do it correctly. 
There’s no way an unquoted, unescaped semicolon (`;`)
can be part of a command. 
Do you want to have a space there? 
Or maybe a colon (`:`)? 
Figure it out.

Comment: I tried to execute the command in command prompt in windows and it was working fine using "java -cp C:\Workspace\CYOV3\bin;C:\Workspace\CYOV3\lib\* org.testng.TestNG testng.xml" not sure how to do it right via ssh.

Comment: You will need to change the semicolon to a colon on Unix. See [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528438/classpath-does-not-work-under-linux)

Comment: Thanks Johan but how should i do it in Linux? since currently we are using Linux server.

Comment: As you're obviously not familiar with the general usage of Linux OS, your best chance is to delegate this to someone who is, e. g. the administrator. Teaching you Unix is far beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a fixed. I used the command below and added it as shell command in jenkins job and build it. It is now executing the command. It was found out that it will not work in Openshift/docker ssh termninal due to it has limited permissions unlike in other linux/unix servers. I used colon to separate the two commands.

java -classpath /var/lib/jenkins/bin:/var/lib/Jenkins/CYOV3/lib/* org.testng.TestNG testng.xml

Thanks a lot for everyone who suggested fixes and all advices